# What is the correct way to initialize a member of a superclass?

Tags: java, subclassing, super

if I have a class that has, for instance a HashMap that is initialized in the constructor like so...

```
public class MySuper{
   HashMap<String,String> foo;

   public MySuper(){
      foo = new HashMap<String,String>();
   }
}
```

my impression (which is incorrect) is that I just need to call super in the subclass and the same initialization will take place, but Eclipse isn't happy with the following syntax...

```
 public class MySub extends MySuper{
      public MySub(){
         super.MySuper()
      }
   }
```

So, I'm curious what the correct way to do this is. Do I have to create a separate method in MySuper that does the initialization and call super on that? (I know that will work), but I was under the impression that there was a way to just call super on the class I'm extending from and have it do whatever it would normally do in its constructor.

TIA

Comment: Someone felt an urge for downvoting it (ridiculous), but I upvoted it back, so now it's on zero. Hopefully someone will remind that person that once he/she was also a beginner, as all of us.

Comment: As the others have said, the main problem you were having (other than the missing `;` is that you should call `super` rather than `super.MySuper`.  And, also as stated, you do not need to explicitly invoke `super` unless you need to provide a parameter list different from the sub constructor's parm list.

Comment: (And it always takes me awhile to remember that it's just `super` for Java -- too many languages dancing around in my head, and they each do it differently.)

Comment: Yeah... I'm always surprised by how mean spirited some of these downvotes are! I mean... it's a perfectly reasonable question, and I take pains to show that I've poked around and tried to figure it out myself, but really... isn't the whole point of this site to spare everyone from having to re-invent every bicycle? As it happens, I'm *not a beginner... I just don't use Java very much, and got hung up on the syntax here. Anyway... I really appreciate the help! Thanks all.

Comment: (Sorry for off-topicness, just one note @Dr.Dredel: I didn't mean you're generally beginner, just in the sense that you're somewhat out of Java practice -- just like I was a few months ago until I needed to refresh/learn it; if one doesn't use a language, it's normal that he gets out of practice; so downvoters are really narrow-minded IMO. (end of off-topicness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just call super() -- also, fyi, in your particular example, you don't even have to write a constructor in the sub-class, it will implicitly call the super class default constructor

Comment: wait, so, you're saying that even if I don't call super foo will be initialized in my subclass and ready to be used?

Comment: well that's awesome, but now I'm not really clear on what the point of super() is, if you don't have anything other than a default constructor. I frequently see it in people's code, but there must be some other constructor they're explicitly avoiding by calling a naked super with no arguments?

Comment: It might be their coding style. The Java compiler inserts the call automatically if you don't do so.

Comment: i normally only use super if i want to explicitly call a super class constructor with args ... if the super class has no default constructor then you MUST explicitly call super (i think the compiler will catch this if you don't)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Even if it's not _necessary_, it can be good practice to make it explicit and unambiguous for readability.

Answer (score 3):

The parameterless constructor of the superclass is called automatically from the subclass.

But if you want to emphasize it in your code, you can use:

```
 public class MySub extends MySuper{
      public MySub(){
         super();
      }
   }
```

super() must be the first statement of your constructor body.

Comment: Actually, `super` does not have to be the first statement.  There simply cannot be anything "threatening" before it (and, alas, defining "threatening" is pretty involved).

Answer (score 1):

By default, subclass's default contructor will call super class's default contructor, so you can just write

```
public MySub(){
    // super(); is automatically called at first line, so you no need call it
    // child init
}
```

or you can call superclass's constructor in first line of child constructor

```
public MySub(){
    super();
    // child init
}
```

If super class have constructor `public MySuper(int i)` that you wish to call, you can write

```
public MySub(){
    super(100);
    // child init
}
```

Comment: if you want to include code in the child constructor, you should add the `super()` sentence as the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You generally dont have to do anything.

The super class no argument constructor is automatically called when a subclass constructor is called.

If you do not have a no argument constructor in the super class, or you want to call another overloaded version then you have to explicitly call via `super` (otherwise your code won't compile, because the super class constructor has to be called, and if the default no-arg constructor is not available, the VM would not know which overload to call).

You do it this way:

`super()`
or

```
 public class MySub extends MySuper{
      public MySub(){
         super();
      }
   }
```

or

```
 public class MySub extends MySuper{
      public MySub(int a, int b){
         super(a, b);
      }
   }
```

See [using super.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
You have no need to call super.MySuper() because super classe's default constructor always invoke implicitly because the first line of child class's constructor is super() by default.

public class MySuper{
   HashMap<String,String> foo;

   public MySuper(){
      foo = new HashMap<String,String>();
   }
}

public class MySub extends MySuper{

}
```